# Coefficients that make a quartic trivariate polynomial non-negative

Tags: polynomials, optimization

Let

$$f(x,y,z)=a_1 x^4+a_2 x^3+a_3 x^2+a_4 x^2y+a_5 x^2z+a_6 y^2+a_7 z^2+a_8 xy+a_9 xz+a_{10} yz+a_{11}x+a_{12}y+a_{13}z$$

be a polynomial of degree $4$. Can we determine coefficients $a_1, \dots, a_{13}$ such that $f(x,y,z) \ge 0$ for all $x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}$?

Any reference (in particular, a systematic approach to solve such problems), suggestion, idea, or comment is welcome. Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1864209/339790)

Comment: Thank you for the reference. I'm just wondering that the Motzkin polynomial is an example which is never negative but cannot be written as a sum of any number of squares https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2016/06/29/positive-polynomials-and-squares/

Comment: Exactly. Not all non-negative polynomials are SOS-decomposable. However, SOS decompositions can often be found via semidefinite programs, which are usually tractable.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments, this can be (conservatively) posed as a sum-of-squares problem.

Here is an implementation in the MATLAB Toolbox YALMIP which has SOS support (disclaimer, I'm the dev)

```
sdpvar a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 a8 a9 a10 a11 a12 a13
sdpvar x y z
f = a1*x^4+a2*x^3+a3*x^2+a4*x^2*y+a5*x^2*z+a6*y^2+a7*z^2+a8*x*y+a9*x*z+a10*y*z+a11*x+a12*y+a13*z
params = [a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 a8 a9 a10 a11 a12 a13];
solvesos([sos(f), sum(params) == 1])
```

The constraint on the sum is added to avoid the trivial zero solution

The polynomial has a lot of structure, so the resulting SDP is pretty small (only 4 monomials are required in the basis)

Answer (score 2):

We can use the [Newton polytope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_polytope). A positive polynomial should have a convex hull defined by even degree monomials. Our polynomial has a polytope representation as can be observed in the following plot.

[image]

In black the convex hull monomials which are

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
x & y & z\\
 4 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 2 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 2 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

and in red the inner monomials which are.

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
x & y & z\\
 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 2 & 0 & 0 \\
 2 & 0 & 1 \\
 2 & 1 & 0 \\
 3 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Accordingly we should have $a_{11}=a_{12}=a_{13}=0$. After that, the polytope is represented as

[image]

Now the convex hull is formed by

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
x & y & z\\
 4 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 2 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 2 \\
 2 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

and this arrangement has chance of positivity. To proceed we can obtain this convex hull

$$
\{x^4,\ x^2,\ y^2,\ z^2\}
$$

using a convenient monomial basis as

$$
\{x^2,\ x,\ y, \ z\}
$$

so our polynomial form can be represented as

$$
f(x,y,z) = Z^{\dagger}B Z
$$

with $Z = \{x^2,\ x,\ y, \ z\}^{\dagger}$ and $B$ a $4\times 4$ matrix of coefficients. At this point we can follow with the analysis performed on the comment references.

NOTE

After the  $B$ determination (definite positiveness) we have the relationships

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
 b_{4,4}&=&a_1 \\
 b_{3,4}+b_{4,3}&=&a_2 \\
 b_{2,4}+b_{4,2}&=&a_4 \\
 b_{1,4}+b_{4,1}&=&a_5 \\
 b_{3,3}&=&a_3 \\
 b_{2,3}+b_{3,2}&=&a_8 \\
 b_{1,3}+b_{3,1}&=&a_9 \\
 b_{2,2}&=&a_6 \\
 b_{1,2}+b_{2,1}&=&a_{10} \\
 b_{1,1}&=&a_7 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to view the polynomial as an affine quadratic form in $(y,z)$ with coefficients that depend on $x$ and the $a_i$'s.  For a fixed $x$, the condition that the form in $(y,z)$ is $\ge 0$ is equivalent to some inequalities in $x$ and $a_i$'s. Now impose the condition that those inequalities hold for all $x$ and you should get some conditions for the $a_i$'s (in principle).

However, in this particular case, note that we must have $f(x,0,0)\ge 0$, so 
$$x(a_1 x^3 + a_2 x^2 + a_3 x + a_{11})\ge 0$$
so this implies $a_{11}=0$.

Now consider $f(0,y,0)\ge 0$ and get $a_{12}=0$. Similarly, from $f(0,0,z)\ge 0$ we ge $a_{13}=0$.

Now write $f=f_4 + f_3 + f_2$, the decomposition into homogenous components. Consider values close to $0$, the dominant contribution is from $f_2$. Therefore, $f_2$ must be a positive semidefinite quadratic form.

Getting back to the idea in the introduction, the Wikipedia article of the types of  [conic sections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_representation_of_conic_sections#Classification) is useful.
More analysis is needed.

We can give possible solutions for $f$ as follow:
$$f = x^2 P(x) + Q_1(x^2, y,z) + Q_2(x,y,z)$$

where $P(x)$ is a positive polynomial of degree $2$, and $Q_1$, $Q_2$ are positive semidefinite quadratic forms.