# Criteria for positive-definiteness of higher-order tensors

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors, multilinear-algebra, positive-semidefinite

**Recall.** A second-order tensor is a bilinear form
$$\label{1}\tag{1}
B(x, y)=\sum_{i, j=1}^d b_{ij}x_iy_j, \qquad \text{where }x, y\in \mathbb R^d.$$
We will always assume, without loss of generality, that $B$ is symmetric; that is, $b_{ij}=b_{ji}$. We say that $B$ is *positive semidefinite* if
$$\label{2}\tag{2}
B(x,x)\ge 0, \qquad \text{for all }x\in\mathbb R^d.$$
There are many criteria to establish whether \eqref{2} holds.

---

I am interested in the analogous problem with an higher degree of multilinearity. Namely, consider the general third-order tensor
$$
T(x, y, z)=\sum_{i,j,k=1}^d t_{ijk}x_iy_jz_k, $$
and the fourth-order tensor
$$
F(x, y, z, w)=\sum_{i,j,k, h=1}^d f_{ijkh}x_iy_jz_kw_h. $$
We say that these are positive semidefinite if
$$\label{3}\tag{3}
T(x,x,x)\ge 0, \qquad \forall x\in \mathbb R^d\text{ with positive entries}, $$
and
$$\label{4}\tag{4}
F(x,x,x,x)\ge 0, \qquad \forall x\in\mathbb R^d.$$

*Remark.* In the third-order case, it is necessary to require that the entries of $x$ are all positive. Without that requirement, only the identically zero tensor $T=0$ would satisfy \eqref{3}.

**My question is**: which criteria are there to establish \eqref{3} and \eqref{4}?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1864209/339790).

Comment: (3) reminds me of [copositive matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copositive_matrix).