# Quadratic form for quartics

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quadratic-forms, quartics

This is an example of a quadratic form

$$x_1 x_2 + x_1x_3=(x_1,x_2,x_3)\begin{pmatrix}0&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\\\frac{1}{2}&0&0\\\frac{1}{2}&0&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{pmatrix}.$$

How could I represent polynomials of degree $4$ by a matrix using linear $x_i$? I do not want to use $x_i x_j$ as left and right vectors.
Do I have to use a 4-dimensional $4\times4\times4\times4$-matrix, if such a definition exists? Of course, I would need the inverse and transpose of such a construction.

$$x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4+ x_1 x_3 x_4^2=(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\begin{pmatrix}&\\4\times4\times4\times4\\\text{matrix?}\\&\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\ x_2 \\x_3 \\x_4\end{pmatrix}?$$

Or can I write a quartic polynom as a product of 2 quadratics that can then be joined to a single matrix?

$$x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4+ x_1 x_3 x_4^2=\left[(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\begin{pmatrix}&\\4\times4\\\text{matrix1?}\\&\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\ x_2 \\x_3 \\x_4\end{pmatrix}\right]\left[(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\begin{pmatrix}&\\4\times4\\\text{matrix2?}\\&\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\ x_2 \\x_3 \\x_4\end{pmatrix}\right]$$

Comment: Polynomials of degree 4 or quartic forms?

Comment: the equivalent of quadric forms (i.e. quartic forms if they exist) to express polynomials of degree 4

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1864209/339790).  It would have been easier to start with the bivariate case.

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. There shall be linear $x_i$ as left and right vectors.

Comment: Degree-$1$ monomials on left and right means you have a quadratic form, not a quartic form.  You either accept degree-$2$ monomials, or you need four sides instead.

Comment: How could I realize 4 sides?

Answer (score 1):

The quadratic form is

$ f_2(x_1,x_2,x_3)=\sum_{i,j=1,3} A_{ij} x_i x_j$.

It involves 6 independent components of $A_{ij}$ due to symmetries: $(A_{12}+A_{21}) x_1 x_2$. We can therefore impose $A_{ij}=A_{ji}$.

The quartic form is

$f_4(x_1,x_2,x_3)=\sum_{i,j,k,l=1,3} B_{ijkl} x_i x_j x_k x_l$.

$B_{ijkl}$ has 81 components, but due to the symmetries $B_{ijkl}=B_{jikl}=B_{kjil}=B_{ljki}$ it has only 15 independent components.

By counting the number of independent components it is clear that not any quartic form (with 15 independent components) can be written as the product of two quadratic forms (with 6 independent components each).

Comment: There aren't actually as many *independent* entries as you say, since quadratic forms are typically required to correspond to symmetric matrices.